# jq - can't extract key values from google safebrowsing json response

Tags: json, jq, safe-browsing

So I've read the `jq` tutorial and played with the `github` `json` responses from  there and extracted some values of some other keys so **I think I understand how the syntax works**. Unfortunately nothing works when attempting to use it on a Google `safe-browsing` `json` response. Here is the full response stored in a variable (did the same for the github examples from `jq` tutorial):

```
echo "$safeb"
{
  "matches": [
{
  "threatType": "MALWARE",
  "platformType": "ALL_PLATFORMS",
  "threat": {
    "url": "http://www.wittyvideos.com"
  },
  "cacheDuration": "300s",
  "threatEntryType": "URL"
  }
 ]
}
```

... and this is what I tried:

```
echo "$safeb" | jq '.matches.threatType'
jq: error (at <stdin>:13): Cannot index array with string "threatType"
```

```
echo "$safeb" | jq '.threatType'
null
```

```
echo "$safeb" | jq '.[] | .threatType'
jq: error (at <stdin>:13): Cannot index array with string "threatType"
```

```
echo "$safeb" | jq '.[] | {type: .threatType}'
jq: error (at <stdin>:13): Cannot index array with string "threatType"
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> .matches.threatType

`.matches` is an array, so you'd have to use `[]` to expand it, e.g.:

```
.matches[].threatType
```

> .threatType

This attempt could be salvaged using `..`, e.g.

```
.. | .threatType? // empty
```

> .[] | .threatType

No comment :-)

> .[] | {type: .threatType}

You probably meant:

```
.matches[] | {type: .threatType}
```

### p.s.

You might want to use `debug` to help debug/understand what's going on.

Also, in future, please don't forget to describe or show the expected output.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, though I am still not clarified as to why my attempts did not work on my input as opposed to the input from the given example in the `jq` tutorial. Specifically, when using `curl 'https://api.github.com/repos/stedolan/jq/commits?per_page=5'` as source, I get results with the syntax for which you commented `"No comment"`: `echo "$jqt" | jq '.[] | .sha'` gives me all SHA hashes from the JSON, as expected. I guess the `.[]` construct works in this case because the array is not named in this JSON. Same for the last syntax, adapted to the new input (but same format).